# What is the Logic Error in my Merge Sort C

Tags: c, logic, mergesort

EDIT: This is in no way a duplicate of my previous question. My code has been changed accordingly to the answer I received from my previous thread and I am still getting these errors, which are not the same ones I was asking about last time.

I am writing code to sort intervals entered by a user using merge sort. It takes input from a user which it stores in a structure `interval` which it uses to sort in ascending order. It uses positive and negative values to check if the interval side is open or closed, but that is not relevant to the code being executed. Below is my code and a sample of the type of output I am getting. Thanks everyone so much in advance for any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct interval{
    int num_left, denum_left;
    int num_right, denum_right;
    int left_state, right_state;
}interval;

interval combine(interval x, interval y);
int combineCheck(interval x, interval y);
int valueCheck(interval x, interval y);
void mergeSort(interval x[], int l, int r);
void merge(interval x[], int l, int m, int r);
interval takeInput();

int main(){
    int response, i;
    char d;
    printf("Enter the number of intervals to input: ");
    scanf("%d", &response);
    interval data[response];

    for(i = 0; i < response; i++){
        data[i] = takeInput();
    }

    mergeSort(data, 0, response-1);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", data[0].num_left, data[1].num_left, data[2].num_left);
    for(i = 0; i < response; i++){
        printf("%d/%d   %d/%d\n", data[i].num_left, data[i].denum_left, data[i].num_right, data[i].denum_right);
    }

}

interval takeInput(){
    interval temp;
    printf("Enter left numerator: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp.num_left);
    printf("Enter left denominator: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp.denum_left);
    printf("Enter right numerator: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp.num_right);
    printf("Enter right denominator: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp.denum_right);
    printf("\n");

    if(temp.num_left < 0){
        temp.num_left = temp.num_left*-1;
        temp.left_state = -1;}
    else{
        temp.left_state = 0;}

    if(temp.num_right < 0){
        temp.num_right = temp.num_right*-1;
        temp.right_state = -1;}
    else{
        temp.right_state = 0;}
    return temp;
}

int combineCheck(interval x, interval y){
    int left, right;
    left = x.num_right * y.denum_left;          //used to find relationship between 2 fractions
    right = y.num_left * x.denum_right;

    if(left == right && (x.right_state + x.left_state) == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(left > right){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

interval combine(interval x, interval y){
    int left, right;                        //used to check if one interval is all encompassing
    left = x.num_right * y.denum_right;
    right = x.denum_right * y.num_right;

    interval temp;
    temp.num_left = x.num_left;
    temp.denum_left = x.denum_left;
    temp.left_state; 
    if(left > right){
        temp.num_right = x.num_right;
        temp.denum_right = x.denum_right;
        temp.right_state = x.right_state;
        return temp;
    }
    temp.num_right = y.num_right;
    temp.denum_right = y.denum_right;
    temp.right_state = y.right_state;
    return temp;
}

int valueCheck(interval x, interval y){
    int first, second;                  //used to check values
    first = x.num_left * y.denum_left;
    second = y.num_left * x.denum_left;
    if(first > second){
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

void mergeSort(interval x[], int l, int r){
    if(l < r){
        int m = l + (r-l)/2;

        mergeSort(x, l, m);
        mergeSort(x, m+1, r);
        merge(x, l, m, r);
    }
}

void merge(interval arr[], int l, int m, int r){
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m-l +1;
    int n2 = r-m;

    interval L[n1], R[n2];

    for(i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for(j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1 + j];
    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    k = l;
    while(i < n1 && j < n2){
        if(valueCheck(L[i], R[j]) == -1){
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
    }

    while(i < n1){
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while(j < n2){
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

[image]

Output as Text:

```
Enter the number of intervals to input: 5
Enter Left numerator: 1
Enter left denominator: 1
Enter right numerator: 1
Enter right denominator: 1

Enter Left numerator: 2
Enter left denominator: 1
Enter right numerator: 2
Enter right denominator: 1

Enter Left numerator: 3
Enter left denominator: 1
Enter right numerator: 3
Enter right denominator: 1

Enter Left numerator: 4
Enter left denominator: 1
Enter right numerator: 4
Enter right denominator: 1


Enter Left numerator: 5
Enter left denominator: 1
Enter right numerator: 5
Enter right denominator: 1

5 5 3
5/1 5/1
5/1 5/1
3/1 3/1
5/1 5/1
5/1 5/1
```

Comment: Post what is shown in the image that you gave as text alongside the question.

Comment: I get two warnings when I compile this - are you ignoring warnings or do you just have them disabled for some reason ? Anyway, the second warning looks interesting: `83:10: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
    temp.left_state;` - is that line meant to do something useful ?

Comment: @PaulR It checks whether the interval is open or closed on the left side, but it is not used in my sorting algorithm, I am just checking one fraction against another.

Comment: It's not checking anything in that line though - it's just an expression which is evaluated and discarded, hence the compiler warning.

Comment: I reopened this question because the bugs in the code are different from the bugs in the original question, thus it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the desired output so it's easy to check if the program behaves correctly? This also serves the purpose of making you think about what the program should really do.

Answer (score 0):

Was just missing an iteration of K after a conditional